# C++ - File I/O and Char arrays

Tags: c++, io, arrays

The following is the problem description:

> The history teacher at your school needs help in grading a True/False test.
>   The students’ IDs and test answers are stored in a file. The first entry in the
>   file contains answers to the test in the form:
>
> TFFTFFTTTTFFTFTFTFTT
>
> Every other entry in the file is the student ID, followed by a blank, followed
>   by the student’s responses. For example, the entry:
>
> ABC54301 TFTFTFTT TFTFTFFTTFT
>
> indicates that the student ID is ABC54301 and the answer to question 1 is
>   True, the answer to question 2 is False, and so on. This student did not
>   answer question 9. The exam has 20 questions, and the class has more than
>   150 students. Each correct answer is awarded two points, each wrong answer
>   gets one point deducted, and no answer gets zero points. Write a program
>   that processes the test data. The output should be the student’s ID, followed
>   by the answers, followed by the test score, followed by the test grade.
>   Assume the following grade scale: 90%–100%, A; 80%–89.99%, B;
>   70%–79.99%, C; 60%–69.99%, D; and 0%–59.99%, F.

This is the program I have made:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//declaring variables
ifstream file("grading.txt");
char key[21];
char id[9];
char student[21];
int score = 0, i;

//initializing arrays
for(i=0; i<21; i++)
{
    key[i]=0;
    student[i]=0;
}
for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    id[i]=0;

//processing the key
file >> key;
file.ignore(100, "\n");

//processing student grades
while(file.good())
{

    file >> id;
    file.ignore();
    getline(file, student);
    file.ignore(100, "\n");

    //comparing key and student answer
    for(i=0; i<21; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(student[i], key[i])
            score += 2;
        else
            score -= 1;
    }

    //outputing student id, score and grade
    cout << "Student ID: " << id;
    cout << "Score: " << score;
    score = (score/(40))*100;
    if(score >= 90 && score <= 100)
        cout << "Grade: A" << endl << endl;
    else if(score >= 80 && score <= 89.99)
        cout << "Grade: B" << endl << endl;
    else if(score >= 70 && score <= 79.99)
        cout << "Grade: C" << endl << endl;
    else if(score >= 60 && score <= 69.99)
        cout << "Grade: D" << endl << endl;
    else if(score >= 0 && score <= 59.99)
        cout << "Grade: F" << endl << endl;
    else
        cout << "Invalid percentage" << endl;
}

//closing file
file.close();

return 0;
}
```

I seem to be getting the following compilation errors: http://pastebin.com/r0Y1xX8M (couldn't edit the errors properly on here, sorry)

Help would be appreciated with the compile errors, and any other suggestions as to how to solve this.

Comment: To be frank, I just skimmed your error, but it seems that it would be a lot easier to use strings instead of char arrays. Also, the reason you get the first error is because "\n" and '\n' are different things.

Comment: In file.ignore, should the second param be a String or a char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is in

```
file.ignore(100, "\n");
```

I believe that you want to use `'\n'` with single quotes rather than double quotes.  single quotes represents a character.  double quotes represents an array or characters(a string)

secondly, I believe that iostream contains a `string` class, which encapsulates the character array.  I believe that `getline` uses that string class.  For using character arrays, my personal preference is [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/), but most of your code seems to be based around iostream, so changing your character arrays to strings might be the simplest change to make.

also, your `if(strcmp(student[i], key[i])` line is passing in characters instead of the character arrays.  I believe that `if(student[i] == key[i])` is what you want to do.

your compilation errors tell you what line of code the error is on, so for the rest of them you can look at your code and think about the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `'\n'` as your delimiter - a character constant, rather than a string literal `"\n"`.

The delimiter, second parameter of [`ignore`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/), is of type `int`, to which a character constant can be converted implicitly; in contrast, a string literal cannot be converted to an `int`, so that is what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: There are other problems apart from that.

Comment: @quasiverse Oh, I'm sure there are! But since this is a homework exercise, we should help posters to find solutions by themselves.

Comment: Like how you should look at this page to see why you're getting an error with getline: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Answer (score 0):

Always look for places with the source file and line number. In this case you can see several of these:

```
c:\users\haxtor\desktop\projects\lab 8 part 2 prob 6\lab 8 part 2 prob 6\problem 6.cpp(34)
```

The important part is the `(34)` saying that there's something wrong on line 34. In this case, the problem on line 34 is that student is a `char` array rather than a string and the problem on line 35 is that `"\n"` should be `'\n'`. There may be more problems. Try and find the other places where line numbers are mentioned and fix them yourself.